# How to popToRootViewController with multiple viewControllers on the navigationController stack and show only one transition?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

How to popToRootViewController having multiple viewControllers (2) on the navigationController stack and show only one transition?

For example VC A pushes VC B, C onto the navigation stack. Now I want to have a smooth animated transition from C to A without showing B at all.

I've tried lots of things but always I see B.

For example I've tried:

```
self.navigationController?.viewControllers.removeLast()
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

And:

```
func popBack<T: UIViewController>(toControllerType: T.Type) {
   if var viewControllers: [UIViewController] = self.navigationController?.viewControllers {
      viewControllers = viewControllers.reversed()
      for currentViewController in viewControllers {
         if currentViewController .isKind(of: toControllerType) {
            self.navigationController?.popToViewController(currentViewController, animated: true)
            break
         }
       }
   }
}
```

As well as popping with animated false then popping with animated true, but always I see B.
There are a lot of SO threads and I've attempted more than just what I've put above.

Comment: `popToRootViewController` is for that purpose ... but what issues you are facing with it ?

Comment: If you are seeing `VC B` when you call `self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)` you have doe something wrong. Assuming you are doing this from a button tap, did you also assign a segue from the button back to `VC B`?

Comment: @DonMag Tap on back button and in ViewWillDissappear I call the method popToRootViewController.  That might be the problem that I need to not automatically segue.

Comment: @bhartsb - yeah.... that won't give you what you want. If you want the Back button to take the user back to the Root controller (which may be considered a little odd and unintuitive for the user, but if that's what you want), then you probably need to remove the `B` view controller from the stack when you arrive at `C`.

Comment: @DonMag I will try that.  The behavior is a product requirement, and although not the norm does make sense in the particular context.

Answer (score 0):

[Storyboard and views](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AG1Xx.png)

```
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

Only using this line worked for me.

Comment: No that is not working for me.  C transitions first to B then to A.  As in my OP I only want to see the transitions from C to A.